# raspbian strech, raspi-config is not responding at first boot

Tags: boot, raspi-config, raspbian-stretch

On boot up, Rainbow Screen was viewed, but after that, below black screen (with 4 raspberry pi logo) was shown.... I tried various commands to open 'raspi-config' to get GUI but didn't succeed,

Only the **Red LED** is continuously On.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't appear to have finished booting.  Could you edit your question and include details of how the green LED flashes during boot?

Comment: Only Red LED is continuos on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed with Noobs-Lite & now working fine...

Answer (score 0):

According to https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting this could be several issues:

1. Bad SD card, either the creation of the SD card was unsuccessful or it is a bad card.
2. Bad power supply, USB cable...

Check trough the troubleshooting page and check your system.

Comment: I reinstalled the raspbian strech by noobs... now issue OS is working...

Comment: Please mark my answer as a answer so the question can be closed as "resolved"!

Comment: SD card/Power supply/Cables are fine